# Red color lost in my tab 10.5

Tags: samsung

I have a Samsung tab s 10.5 inch. Once I try the Samsung code `*#0*#` and try to check the red color it gives a black screen, but all other color tests working fine – even tab working fine but any red color showing black  in all pics. I went to Samsung, they told problems is in Lcd or digitizer.

Any one can help please?

[image]

Comment: If Samsung service already said it's a problem in the LCD or digitizer (i.e. it's a hardware issue), there's nothing that can be done software-side. They should have offered you to repair it.

Comment: I see YouTube's and Chrome's icon red enough, so it doesn't seem to be OS/software issue. Can you take the photo of your screen instead? Otherwise, it's hardware issue and not something we can suggest, other than perhaps buy new digitizer or have it replaced by Samsung.

Answer (score 0):

If the test is not displaying any red this is your LCD (all colors are created using 3 LED (light emitting Diodes) Red Green Blue (RGB)  Sadly your R is DEAD.  It might be something as simple as a loose correction which a technician with a test kit and some soldering could fix.

But I doubt you could do it yourself sorry to say.  Find a good computer repair shop near you.... Or contact Samsung and find an "authorized" repair shop if you are wonder warranty.

Good LUCK!